# what is the best way to use SharePoint 2013 site collection list views in sub-sites?

Tags: 2013, list-view, custom-list

Since we cannot import the list view web parts in SharePoint 2013 which was possible in SharePoint 2010, what is best feasible OOTB solution which can be used here.

Comment: the best solution for what?

Comment: to use root site list views in sub sites.

Comment: please let me know if there is any feasible way here

Comment: I'm not sure but is there no list view webpart in sp 2013?

Comment: yes. but can we display the views apart from Content query WP in any other way which looks similar to the OOTB views.

Comment: so is this a question for opinions or do you really have no solution?

Comment: currently I am using AEListViewWebpart2013. i want to change it as I want the OOTB view with search functionality. so need more options with it